# Multiple WidgetsBindingObserver widgets performances

Tags: flutter, dart

I would simply like to know if there is any performances issue by using in multiple widgets the `WidgetsBindingObserver` and more specifically, the call to :

```
 @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        break;
    }
  }
```

Is it the same listener for the whole or is it memory consuming for multiple listeners added to multiple places ?